# Dart best practices, which one is preferred `as` or type annotation for local variables when downcasting

Tags: dart

```
final box = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox; // using as
final RenderBox box = context.findRenderObject(); // using type annotation
```

Both of them does the job, but according to Dart best practices which one of them should be used? I tried but couldn't find much information in documentation.

Comment: best practice would be to keep same strategy for the entire team no matter which one you choose.

Comment: Even Google developers don't stick to one, I've seen many cases.

Comment: @AnirudhBagri I have added my own answer, you can see we shouldn't stick to anyone blindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always try to avoid `as` as much as you can, and use type annotation because following code won't show any compile-time error and would say you're good to go:

```
final foo = 1 as String; // no error
```

And this one would stop us from doing weird stuffs:

```
final String bar = 1; // error
```

*I wish Dart developers had mentioned this sort of example in documentation.*

Comment: Well, this only checks for pretty trivial constants. As soon as you throw in a variable, you get only the runtime exception.

Comment: @Eiko Could you please explain it a bit further?

Comment: `dynamic x = 1; final String bar = x; ` will only throw at runtime. There is not that much more useful checking. Also note that your code in your question might easily break in the future, when `context.findRenderObject()` will *not* return a RenderBox but some other `RenderObject`. I was using something similar, and indeed it broke. You really should only rely on `RenderObject` here, and then just use `final renderObject = ...;` and let the type system do its job.

Comment: But that's absolutely not a solution, because when you only use `final renderObject = context.findRenderObject();` without down-casting it, you can't really use `renderObject.localToGlobal(...);` compile time error!

Comment: This is a tricky situation - use the approach that lets you find the problem easy if it happens. :-) But both will only crash at runtime. Wrapping it with `is RenderBox` could be somewhat useful as it prevents the App from crashing (pretty bad), but obviously the useful code wouldn't run at all. So the advice  'be consistent' is probably the best effort. :-) (And I agree that the RenderBox is often needed and much more useful; not sure if it's even guaranteed with most widgets...)

Comment: See, if you're talking about runtime crashes, they are hard to prevent, but at least you have control over compile time errors, so I think it is better to solve compile time error, else your code won't even compile.

Comment: I totally agree, but neither will give you a compiler error in any situation that you would use one of them. Both will do checks at runtime. Or can you provide a meaningful example where one gives a compile time error?

Comment: @Eiko In your previous comment, you said that my code may break in future and I shouldn't do it this way rather simply use `final renderObject = ...`, I knew my code wasn't breaking and probably it won't. I hope I am clear to you.

Comment: Stackoverflow is discouraging long discussions. If you need to use it, do so and don't feel bad about it. I don't think there's a perfect solution here, or one that would already break at compile time.